# Python MySQL Connector throwing authentication error when converted to exe

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have a python script that connects to a MySQL server hosted in the cloud and allows the user to perform some basic queries. When running the script in PyCharm, everything works exactly as expected with no issues. In order to distribute this I have tried converting it to an exe using both PyInstaller and py2exe, and both produce the same problem - when attempting to connect to the server through the exe file, the following error occurs:

[image: auth error]

I have tried changing the auth_plugin to "sha256_password" and "mysql_clear_password", and both produce the same error (with respective text). I have tried uninstalling all mysql.connector packages using pip and making sure to install mysql.connector.python. I have tried using pyinstaller and py2exe, adding ssl_disabled and ssl_ca arguments in the connect method. All attempts produce the same error, but only when converted to an exe, all works perfectly in PyCharm.

Comment: Searching around I found [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74476907/mysql-connector-errors-notsupportederror-authentication-plugin-mysql-native-pa), which at first reading indicates that the module responsible for the authentication isn't included with the `py2exe` binary. [Manually importing the auth module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75398966/) may be a possible workaround, alternatively, use the [hidden import](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-hidden-import) flag.  Should this fix your issue you may consider adding a self-answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Manually importing the auth module using hidden import solved this issue